# Does the IntelliGender gender prediction test have 78% accuracy?

Tags: medical-science, consumer-products

In 2009, [CNN described](http://edition.cnn.com/2009/HEALTH/06/09/gender.prediction.test/) Intelligender, an over-the-counter test that predicts the gender of an unborn baby based on hormones in the mother's urine.

> It claims that within 10 minutes of taking the urine test, a woman will be able to tell her baby's gender. The specimen will turn green if it's a boy, and orange if it's a girl.

[...]

> The gender predictor test boasts a 78 to 80 percent accuracy rate, according to the latest IntelliGender report.

This claimed accuracy seems quite high. Is there any scientific study backing up these figures?

Comment: based on reading the majority of reviews on drugstore pages, parenting/pregnancy forums & blogs, etc, it's about as accurate as a coin-toss: take it for fun, but don't count on it being right - even the *company* claims it's "for fun"

Comment: I don't know if 80% accuracy is that high. Remember that accuracy of a random guess is 50%.